# Adding text to string

Tags: swift, parsing, markdown

I am styling some dynamic markdown, however the framework I am using for styling doesnt support nested tags for links.

I need to parse the string and close the styling markdown tags effectively this :

```
    "__Some bold text [FIRST LINK](https://FIRSTLINK.COM \"FIRST LINK\"), more bold text.__\n\n additional text \n\n
 *some italic text[SECOND LINK](https://SECONDLINK.COM) ending text,*"
```

to this:

```
    "__Some bold text __[FIRST LINK](https://FIRSTLINK.COM \"FIRST LINK\")__, more bold text.__\n\n additional text \n\n
 *some italic text*[SECOND LINK](https://SECONDLINK.COM)* ending text,*"
```

This is only really going to be for bold and italic text. I started going down the route of

```
var str = "__Some bold text [FIRST LINK](https://FIRSTLINK.COM \"FIRST LINK\"), more bold text.__\n\n additional text \n\n *some italic text[SECOND LINK](https://SECONDLINK.COM) ending text,*"

    let bold = str.components(separatedBy: "__")
    for var string in bold {
        if let matchedIndex = string.index(of: "[") {
            string.insert(contentsOf: "__", at: matchedIndex)
        }
    }
```

But wondered, is there a better way to do this in Swift?

Edit  - for clarity - essentially I need to modify the existing string to have closed tags prior to a link tag and re opened after a link tag - this prevents the links from being nested with the style tags and allows the  styler framework to apply attributed strings accordingly

EDIT --- in line with @Linus comment here is the results of the regex (note running these out side of an extension in order to be able to test in a playground

```
var str = "__Some bold text [FIRST LINK](https://FIRSTLINK.COM \"FIRST LINK\"), more bold text.__\n additional text \n *some italic text[SECOND LINK](https://SECONDLINK.COM) ending text,*\n__sfdadhfjkh [THIRD LINK](https://THIRDLINK.COM \"THIRD LINK\"), more bold text.__"

do {
    var regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern:  "(\\[.*?\\))" , options: [.caseInsensitive])
    var newString = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: str, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, str.utf16.count), withTemplate: "__$1__")
    print("\nFirst regex  __$1__  \n\n\(newString)")

    regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern:  "(\\[.*?\\))" , options: [.caseInsensitive])
        var newerString = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: str, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, str.utf16.count), withTemplate: "*$1*")
        print("\nSecond Regex *$1* \n\n"+newerString)
} catch { print("ERROR: searchFor regex (\("(\\[.*?\\))")) on string (\(str)) failed") }
```

Printed results

```
First regex  __$1__  

__Some bold text __[FIRST LINK](https://FIRSTLINK.COM "FIRST LINK")__, more bold text.__
 additional text 
 *some italic text__[SECOND LINK](https://SECONDLINK.COM)__ ending text,*
__sfdadhfjkh __[THIRD LINK](https://THIRDLINK.COM "THIRD LINK")__, more bold text.__

Second Regex *$1* 

__Some bold text *[FIRST LINK](https://FIRSTLINK.COM "FIRST LINK")*, more bold text.__
 additional text 
 *some italic text*[SECOND LINK](https://SECONDLINK.COM)* ending text,*
__sfdadhfjkh *[THIRD LINK](https://THIRDLINK.COM "THIRD LINK")*, more bold text.__
```

I need to have both Italic and strong tags amended on the same string in order to pass it to a view to be styled

Comment: Looks like a job for regular expressions.

Comment: Your example doesn't work, right? I don't see anything that inserts the `__` after the link's closing parenthesis.

Comment: @NRitH the example isn't complete as its just an indication of the route i was going to take....

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following String extension that allows you to find strings that match a certain regex pattern and replace it with some other string:

```
extension String {
    mutating func replaceOccurrence(ofPattern pattern: String, with replacementString: String) {
        do {
            let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [.caseInsensitive])
            self = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: self, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, utf16.count), withTemplate: replacementString)
        } catch { print("ERROR: searchFor regex (\(pattern)) on string (\(self)) failed") }
    }
}
```

Then, you could replace `(\[.*?\))` with `__$1__`, like this:

```
str.replaceOccurrence(ofPattern: "(\\[.*?\\))", with: "__$1__")
```

---

## Explanation

...in case you're unfamiliar with [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

**The regex:**

`(` - opening parenthesis, that creates a new group which is later used to insert the matched string back into the replacement string
`\[` - matches a bracket; needs to be escaped using `\` to disable the bracket's regex meaning & match the actual character instead
`.*` - matches any character...
`?` - ...until...
`\)` - ...the next closing parenthesis; this one also needs to be escaped to match the actual character, and not create a new group
`)` - closes the group

**The replacement:**

`__` - your replacement string: opening bold range in this case
`$1` - inserts the previously matched group here
`__` - again, your replacement string: closing bold range in this case

*Fun-Fact:* in Swift, you need to escape escaping characters, like `\\` to make sure the code compiles, because Xcode thinks, you're trying to escape a character from the string at compile-time.
That's why the regex isn't `(\[.*?\))`, but `(\\[.*?\\))`.

Comment: Hey thanks @Linus - this looks really good - however  there are a couple of issues.

I ideally want to just amend the text in place rather than pulling out specific sections: for instance running the following : 

do {
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern:  "(\\[.*?\\))" , options: [.caseInsensitive])
    var newString = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: str, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, str.utf16.count), withTemplate: "__$1__")
    print("First regex \(newString)")
} catch { print("ERROR: searchFor regex (\("(\\[.*?\\))")) on string (\(str)) failed") }

Comment: only returns 
First regex __Some bold text __[FIRST LINK](https://FIRSTLINK.COM "FIRST LINK")__, more bold text.__

Comment: Also I need to run the same for the italic - which changing the pattern to '"*$1*"'
returns __Some bold text *[FIRST LINK](https://FIRSTLINK.COM "FIRST LINK")*, more bold text.__

Comment: Sorry regex is something I have never mastered :(

Comment: No problem. I’m having a hard time to understand what you’re actually trying to do, as I apparently misunderstood it at least in some way. Can you please, in a clean and *compact* example, show what exactly you’re trying to do? @user499846

Comment: sorry, I have updated to hopefully make it a little clearer

Comment: So why does the solution I provided not work for you?

Comment: I have updated the question with the results - thanks!

Comment: Were you able to solve your issue? Do you still need help? @user499846

Comment: I solved it via a fix in the style framework - I am still interested to know for future reference though - or if someone else comes across this looking for a reoccuring pattern match for html / markup

Comment: Ok then please make sure to accept the answer if it pointed you in the right direction. I can also update it to match your fix if you want to.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the answer didn't solve the problem as indicated in the Edit to the question. I took a completely different route and leave the markup as is and make changes to the styling framework.

Comment: Ah I see. Mind sharing your solution? Post it as answer and then accept it. I'd be interested in knowing what did the job, since I'm still not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: The solution is unrelated to how the question is posed here - the question was 'how do i parse this string to close a tag before opening another' where the solution was to amend the styling framework which is very specific to the framework methods and unrelated to how to parse the string  - so very out of context